# Testing RequireJS modules with QUnit

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, qunit

I'm trying to test a requirejs module that has two dependencies (jquery and another custom module).

**myModule-Test.js**

```
'use strict';

(function() {

    var uut,
        modulePath= "../../main/webapp/js/modules/myModule.js";


    module("myModule object test suite", {
        setup: function() {
            QUnit.stop();

            require.config({
                map: {
                  "*": {
                     "jquery": "../../main/webapp/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js",
                     "screenLabelsResolver": "../../main/webapp/js/modules/my-screen-labels-resolver"
                  }
                }
            });
            require([modulePath], function(module) {
                uut = module;
                QUnit.start();
            });
        },
        teardown: function() {
            require.undef(modulePath);
            require.config({
                map: {
                  "*": {
                     "jquery": "jquery",
                      "screenLabelsResolver": "../../main/webapp/js/modules/my-screen-labels-resolver"
                  }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    test("Given A Page I Expect The Global myModule Object To Exist", function() {
        ok( uut !== undefined );
    });



}());
```

I am using require.config to pass in the dependencies with stop() and a Start().

**myModule.js**

```
'use strict';

define(["jquery", "screenLabelsResolver"], function($, screenLabelsResolver) {

    var metaTag = $("meta[name='application-name']"),
        currentBrand = metaTag.attr("data-brand"),
        currentWidth,
        viewState,
        sessionTimeoutValue = metaTag.attr("data-sessiontimeoutvalue"),
        sessionTimeoutWarningValue = metaTag.attr("data-sessiontimeoutwarningvalue"),
        screenLabels = {},
        perceptionDate = metaTag.attr("data-todayatmidnight"),
        currentViewportWidth = $(window).width(),
        isViewState = metaTag.attr("data-isviewstate"),
        isTouch = $("html").hasClass("touch")

    return {
        metaTag: function () {
            return metaTag;
        },
        currentBrand: function(){
            return currentBrand;
        },
        currentViewportWidth: function(){
            return currentViewportWidth;
        },
        isViewState: function(){
            return isViewState;
        },
        sessionTimeoutValue: function(){
            return sessionTimeoutValue;
        },
        sessionTimeoutWarningValue: function(){
            return sessionTimeoutWarningValue;
        },
        getPerceptionDate: function(){
            return perceptionDate;
        },
        getOrientation: function () {
            return ( window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90 ) ? "landscape" : "portrait";
        },
        isTouch: function(){
            return isTouch;
        },
        screenLabels: function() {
            if (screenLabels = {}) {
                screenLabels = screenLabelsResolver( metaTag.attr("data-viewstate") /* or however you want to get the current viewstate name */ );
            }
            return screenLabels;
        }
    };
});
```

I get the error "`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`" where I try to use jQuery ($) in line `var metaTag = $("meta[name='application-name']")`.

Somehow, jQuery is not loaded properly by the time the call is made.

My question that is this the correct approach to test r.js modules with multiple dependencies?  If so what's the fundamental error in the above code?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your error is here:  `function($, screenLabelsResolver)`.

Comment: Probably just remove the dollar parameter?

Comment: are you sure that the jQuery shim works? Maybe dumping it with a `console.log()` at the first line in the module.

Comment: Have you read HOW TO USE REQUIREJS WITH JQUERY http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html?

Comment: I need the $ to be on the module as it depends on jQuery object although test passes once I removed it my app fails. Reading through doc now again.