# "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require" (using babel.js output)

Tags: javascript, gulp, phantomjs, babeljs, qunit

My PhantomJS Runner does not seem to be aware of `esModule`s.

my `es2015` code is parsed by babel.js and turned into `es5` code
When i run the `qunit-phantomjs-runner`, I get this error

```
..../myapp/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs ..../myapp/node_modules/qunit-phantomjs-runner/runner.js file:////..../myapp/tests/index.html
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

  file:////..../myapp/.tmp/js/app.js:5

Test failed: global failure
    Failed assertion: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'App.rootElement = '#ember-testing'')
file:////..../myapp/tests/tests.js:2
```

Here is the 'TestSuite' That i pass into phantomjs through this command in the runner:

```
page = require('webpage').create();
...
...
page.open(url, function (status) { ... }); //url is the test/index.html file
```

Here is the index.html file itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="runner.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <div id="ember-testing-container">
    <div id="ember-testing"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/ember/ember.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="../.tmp/js/compiled-templates.js"></script>
  <script src="../.tmp/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.js"></script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code causing the problem:

```
/* global Ember */

'use strict';

var _ember = require('ember'); // <--- breaks at this line, also if i try to access exports variable

var _ember2 = _interopRequireDefault(_ember);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var App = _ember2.default.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {});

App.IndexRoute = _ember2.default.Route.extend({
  model: function model() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

[similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449220/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-require-at) questions [aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107323/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-x-when-using-grunt-test-in-yeoman) much [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434978/babel-generated-code-causes-error-exports-is-undefined) to [me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166859/testing-requirejs-modules-with-qunit).

## I'm using

- "babel-core": "^6.4.5"
- "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13"
- "gulp-qunit": "^1.3.0"
- "gulp": "^3.9.0"
- "phantomjs": "^1.9.0"

Comment: I know you linked to this question, but it is indeed a duplicate. You need to use a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify, just like it says.

Comment: That or don't use import/export and instead access the global.